# JMS beans don´t get initialized

Tags: spring-jms

Apparently I have set up two different applications to use spring + IBM MQ JMS, deployed in JBoss. The issue is that in one of them the beans get initialized ( and the Messages caught ), while in the other not.

Instead of pasting here any of the poms or confs.xml, I would like to share what is visible  in the server log when both apps are deployed.

### The working one shows:

21:15:18,421 INFO  [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Using JTA UserTransaction: org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction@1d16ee6
21:15:18,421 INFO  [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Using JTA TransactionManager: com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerDelegate@8a35f2
21:15:18,422 INFO  [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Using JTA TransactionSynchronizationRegistry: com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionSynchronizationRegistryImple@1298965
21:15:18,450 INFO  [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Initializing ExecutorService  'schedulerTaskExecutor'
21:15:18,597 INFO  **[org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Starting beans in phase 2147483647**
21:15:18,602 INFO  [com.volvo.jvs.runtime.springutils.SpringContextBootstrapper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) --- Active Spring Profiles ---
21:15:18,602 INFO  [com.volvo.jvs.runtime.springutils.SpringContextBootstrapper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) 'localdev'
21:15:18,603 INFO  [com.volvo.jvs.runtime.springutils.SpringContextBootstrapper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) 'jboss'
21:15:18,603 INFO  [com.volvo.jvs.runtime.springutils.SpringContextBootstrapper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) --- JVS Managed System Properties ---
21:15:18,603 INFO  [com.volvo.jvs.runtime.springutils.SpringContextBootstrapper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) com.volvo.jvs.runtime system property is 'jboss'
21:15:18,684 INFO  [com.volvo.jvs.runtime.springutils.SpringContextBootstrapper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) com.volvo.jvs.env system property is 'localdev'
21:15:18,778 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/pos-web]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
21:15:18,778 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
21:15:18,778 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 0 ms
21:15:18,923 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015859: Deployed "pos-web.war" (runtime-name : "pos-web.war")

### The one not working does not include the "Starting beans", having similar surrounding info.

21:11:36,980 INFO  [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) Using JTA UserTransaction: org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction@1f87d37
21:11:36,980 INFO  [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) Using JTA TransactionManager: com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerDelegate@188fcc3
21:11:36,980 INFO  [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) Using JTA TransactionSynchronizationRegistry: com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionSynchronizationRegistryImple@1bb6420
21:11:36,997 INFO  [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) Initializing ExecutorService  'schedulerTaskExecutor'
21:11:37,011 INFO  [com.volvo.jvs.runtime.springutils.SpringContextBootstrapper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) --- Active Spring Profiles ---
21:11:37,012 INFO  [com.volvo.jvs.runtime.springutils.SpringContextBootstrapper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) 'localdev'
21:11:37,012 INFO  [com.volvo.jvs.runtime.springutils.SpringContextBootstrapper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) 'jboss'
21:11:37,012 INFO  [com.volvo.jvs.runtime.springutils.SpringContextBootstrapper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) --- JVS Managed System Properties ---
21:11:37,012 INFO  [com.volvo.jvs.runtime.springutils.SpringContextBootstrapper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) com.volvo.jvs.runtime system property is 'jboss'
21:11:37,013 INFO  [com.volvo.jvs.runtime.springutils.SpringContextBootstrapper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) com.volvo.jvs.env system property is 'localdev'
21:11:37,026 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/start]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
21:11:37,026 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
21:11:37,027 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 0 ms
21:11:37,331 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS015865: Replaced deployment "start-web.war" with deployment "start-web.war"

### Question

So...why is that DefaultLifecycleProcessor not called?

Answer (score 0):

It will only be called if at least one `SmartLifecycle` bean is found (such beans are added to groups or phases). If you don't see that message it means no beans are found.

One common error is to have a bean (that's not a `SmartyLifecycle`) with the same name that replaces the listener container bean.

You need to look further back in the log where the bean definitions are processed and beans instantiated.